# Multiple XIB's same view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am wondering if it is possible to have multiple XIB's on the iPhone screen at the same time. So the user can switch from view to view like that.

Mainly what I want to be able to do, is something like the current FaceBook and YouTube app.

Because currently I have lots of views in my application (an all in one calculator) but I would like them to interact more fluidly. (Maybe swipe you finger from the edge of the screen to go to the previously used calculator. Or swipe down from the top to see all of the calculators in a list. Hopefully the thing that swipes down would be another view.

Hopefully you understand what I want to do, and it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is instantiate your second xib as a view controller inside your first view controller. From there you can simple add the view property of the second as a subview of the first.. that was kind of a mouthful:

```
UIViewController *mySecondXibsViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondXib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[mySecondXibsViewController.view setFrame:someCGRect];
[self.view addSubview:mySecondXibsViewController.view];
```

Or if you were to be using storyboards it would look like this:

```
UIViewController *mySecondXibsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someID"];
```